# How to extract multi line and white space including text from another text using RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my text:

```
[[>
Check this out!

And also this one!

Well, I also have this 
[[MyVariable>5:15]]
```

I want to extract:

```
Check this out!

And also this one!

Well, I also have this
```

and

```
MyVariable
```

and

```
5:15
```

When it's only `[[MyVariable>5:15]]` I can extract values using this RegEx: `/\[\[(.*)\]\]/g`. However, I'm unable to get multi-line version which starts with `[[>`.

I tried `\[\[\>(\s\S)\]\]` with no luck.

How do I get what I want?

(I'm using JavaScript)

Comment: `\[\[\>[\s\S]*?\]\]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see `[[..>..]]` as a structure which you need to deal with it. If you want to capture everything before and after `>`:

```
\[\[([^>]*)>([^[\]]*)
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zN8aN1/1)

Comment: Hello revo, thanks for fast reply! Actually, my structure is something like `[[> ... ]]`. But there is also `[[MyVariable>5:15]]` structure inside it. However, as you can see, two structures are nested, they are not separated. I mean, the closing `]]` is used for both inner structure and the outer one.

Comment: Do you know what? I can even prefer `[[MyVariable>5:15
...
]]` structure but I think it could be harder. I can update the question if you think that's easy to do so? After the `5:15` part, a new line should be expected in that scenario. I can also ask this as a new question if you'd like? And I should be able to extract `MyVariable>5:15` part too, of course.

Comment: Please add a more illustrative sample input in your question with desired parts to be captured. Please say how many nested levels are likely to happen. @scaryguy

Comment: I think I've solved it with help of your answer. I'll check it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this.

```
/([^\[\[>]*)[A-Za-z0-9]([^>[\]]*)/g
```

If you haven't heard of it, [regexr](http://regexr.com/) is a pretty cool place to experiment with regex.